# How to display post from current Taxonomy in archive page?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I am using the following code to display a random post from the current category in category archive page (using archive.php). However, when in Tag or Taxonomy archive pages, the post is not correctly displayed from the current Tag or Taxonomy (due to the limitation of category only). How can I modify to make it work with Tag and Taxonomy (or just Taxonomy since Category and Tag are also Taxonomies). Thanks!

```
// assign the variable as current category
$currentcategory = $cat;

// concatenate the query
$args = 'showposts=1&cat=' . $currentcategory . '&orderby=rand';

$random_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop

if ( $random_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $random_query->have_posts() ) {
$random_query->the_post();

// custom template for the random post

}

} else {

// no posts found

}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Edited code in regarding to s_ha_dum's answer:

```
<?php // The Query

if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
    $qobj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

// concatenate the query
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $qobj->term_id
                )
            )
        );
}

$random_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $random_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $random_query->have_posts() ) {
        $random_query->the_post(); ?>

//HTML tempalte

<?php   }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: posts_per_page doesn't work, it's only returning one post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to grab the queried object for the page and fill in your taxonomy information dynamically.

```
if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
    $qobj = get_queried_object();
    // var_dump($qobj); // debugging only
    
    // concatenate the query
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $qobj->term_id,
    //    using a slug is also possible
    //    'field' => 'slug', 
    //    'terms' => $qobj->name
        )
      )
    );

    $random_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // var_dump($random_query); // debugging only

    if ($random_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($random_query->have_posts()) {
          $random_query->the_post();
          // Display
        }
    }
}
```

It is not clear if you need this Loop *in addition to* the main Loop or as a replacement for it. I am assume this is "in addition" as it would effectively remove archive functionality if it were to replace the main query. You;d have no real archives, just a random post from the archive which isn't very friendly all by itself.

You could use the `category.php` and the `tag.php` archive templates to process tags and categories separately. You don't need to use `archive.php`.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

Comment: Thanks! The code is awesome but output the whole "object" of the current taxonomy (due to var_dump?). I modified it a bit to get rid of var_dump and it works well without the output "object". I am not sure whether the following code is correct in logic and please help to check it out.

Comment: Yes, a `var_dump` is almost always going to be debugging. I put that in there so you could "see" what you are dealing with. What "following code"?

Comment: Oops, I cannot add code in comment. I've added the modified code in the original question.

Comment: @Milo : You want that query inside the conditional as well as the Loop that uses it. See the edit. My Fault.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I need this Loop in addition to the main Loop. I'm doing a slider at the top of category.php page to show the most viewed post from the current category being viewed. [link](http://labs.mixtapes.tv/videos)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the main query with a custom `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );

function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() or ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page',  1 );
    }

}
```

and the usual loop, instead of the additional `WP_Query()`.

Comment: Thanks! `pre_get_posts ` is great but it modifies the main loop and I won't be able to display posts on archive pages. But really good an idea to achieve the goal in a smart way.

Comment: ok, if you need the extra WP_Query you should check out the nice answer given by @s_ha_dum below.